TUS Python Upload to CloudFlare Ignores Upload-Metadata header
Might be too specific for stack overflow but i'll give it a shot.
I'm trying to upload to CloudFlare Stream using the TUS python client: https://github.com/tus/tus-py-client
As per CloudFlare's Documentation here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/stream-videos-initiate-video-uploads-using-tus and Here: https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/uploading-videos/resumable-uploads/
The video itself uploads fine and the other headers like creator work but anything I put in the Upload-Metadata header is ignored. Including copy and pasting the example header from the documentation.
My code is as follows:
size = os.fstat(file.fileno()).st_size
            
            # Set more headers.
            metadatatitle = str(base64.b64encode(title.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'))
            #flash(metadatatitle)

            my_client = client.TusClient('https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/myaccountid/stream', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer MyBearerCode', 'Tus-Resumable': '1.0.0', 'Upload-Length': str(size), 'Upload-Metadata': "name " + metadatatitle, 'Upload-Creator': creator})

            uploader = my_client.uploader(file_stream=file, chunk_size=5242880)

            uploader.upload()

I have tried using the example header in the documentation to rule out my base64 encoding method. I have also tried using the my_client.set_headers({'HEADER_NAME': 'HEADER_VALUE'}) to set the header instead to no avail.
